# Confluent-Kafka Python : How to list all topics programmatically

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a kafka broker running in my local system. To communicate with the broken using my Django based web application I am using [confluent-kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#module-confluent_kafka.admin) wrapper. However by browsing through the admin api, I could not find out any api for listing kafka topics. (The topics are created pragmatically and are dynamic).

Is there any way I could list them within my program?
The requirement is that, if my worker reboots all assigned consumers listening to those topics will have to be re-initialized so I want to loop to all the topics and assign a consumer to each.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how to do it:

```
>>> from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient

>>> conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'vps01:9092,vps02:9092,vps03:9092'}
>>> kadmin = AdminClient(conf)

>>> kadmin.list_topics().topics # Returns a dict(). See example below.
{'topic01': TopicMetadata(topic01, 3 partitions),}
```

I hope that helps.

**Edit**: There may be newer **API**s these days (I don't know), but above is how I used to do and it worked well.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways you can achieve it:

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer

consummer_config = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'group1'
}
consumer = Consumer(consummer_config)
consumer.list_topics().topics
```

This will return a dictionary something like this:

```
{'raw_request': TopicMetadata(raw_request, 4 partitions),
 'raw_requests': TopicMetadata(raw_requests, 1 partitions),
 'idw': TopicMetadata(idw, 1 partitions),
 '__consumer_offsets': TopicMetadata(__consumer_offsets, 50 partitions)}
```

the other way is already posted by [@NYCeyes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59429243/7547278)

Answer (score 1):

Try searching again for `list_topics`

https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.1/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.list_topics

https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.1/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Producer.list_topics